# angularjs SPA issue to load new contents?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS and studying about routing. As i have created a demo application and it is working fine but the issue is whenever i click on the anchor tag it loads the required document 'x.html', once loaded in the ngView next time same content is shown but it should show new content as 'x.html' is dynamic page which shows the date Time from server.

There is no more hits to the server. How can i make changes to the app.config so that it shows new content every time. Is it against the SPA as it will take more time to load the things again.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it might not be an issue with router or angular. Can you pls post the code you are writing to display dynamic time and date?